# Reject email if "rcpt to" does not match relay_domain - Postfix

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server

My mail server currently shows up in mxtoolbox as Open Relay.

Objective: Allow SMTP connection only when `RCPT TO:` says example.com

What changes should I make in it so that, it would reject the connection immediately when it knows that the `RCPT TO:` is not `example.com`. Currently, I am being spammed & I am rejecting email based on `check_recipient_access`.

**A test email:**

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 <HOSTNAME> ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
ehlo test.com
250-<HOSTNAME>
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

**Current Situation:**

```
mail from: test@test.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: test@test2.com
250 2.1.5 Ok
```

**Expecting:**

```
mail from: test@test.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: test@test2.com
REJECT
```

and

```
mail from: test@test.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: test@example.com
250 2.1.5 Ok
```

The output of `postconf -n`

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = <hostname>, localhost.<domain>, localhost
mydomain = example.com
myhostname = <hostname>
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 10.32.247.0/24
myorigin = <hostname>
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = example.com
relayhost = [10.32.247.125]:10000
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_destination, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, permit
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_recipient_access pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_access,  reject_unauth_pipelining,  reject_non_fqdn_recipient,  reject_unknown_recipient_domain,  permit_mynetworks,  reject_unauth_destination,  permit
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Maillog file in verbose mode: http://pastebin.com/9q7f5DFp

**My current scenario:**

Email --> Postfix accepts --> Checks Headers --> Discards if it doesn't belong to example.com

**Expected:**

Email --> Postfix checks RCPT TO: == example.com --> Rejects if it is not and does not process it further

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show your postfix configuration (output of `postconf -n`)

Comment: What did you change compared to the default? You should be able to see that easily (compare to `postconf -d`). Postfix is not an open relay by default.

Comment: Please describe every bit of the network connection between your upstream Internet connection and this mail server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton How is it related? I don't seem to understand. This is a public Internet facing mail server & must only accept mail connections directed to example.com & not allow any other connection SMTP handshake.

Comment: Are you 100% certain that it's public and internet facing? How do you know?

Comment: @MichaelHampton What do you mean ? I am the server administrator. :-) In case you are wondering its NAT'ed.

Comment: So it's _not_ directly on the Internet. Go back and answer my last question, then.

Comment: Pubic IP --> NAT --> Postfix Server (Private IP)  --(Forwards to)-->  Another Relay Server . Anything else I can tell ?

Comment: It's indeed strange. Based on your `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`, postfix should [reject all email when RCPT TO domains](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_unauth_destination) that doesn't belongs to your domain. Can you [enable verbose mode in postfix](http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html#verbose) and post the maillog output in the question?

Comment: Have you tried postfix in verbose mode?

Comment: @masegaloeh  http://pastebin.com/9q7f5DFp

Answer (score 1):

Here the key line from your mail.log

> NOQUEUE: discard: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: : Recipient address triggers DISCARD action; from= to= proto=ESMTP helo=

In postfix, `DISCARD` means postfix pretends to accept the email but in reality it will sent the email to /dev/null (in other means, it will discard the email). So, when you check with telnet, postfix will reply with "OK I accept it".

Comment: I have added a couple more lines to the question. I want Postfix to reject in the beginning itself not accept it and send it to `/dev/null`. This is possible. I want to know how.

Comment: Edit the question and add the contents of ` pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_access` . What's the purpose of this restriction?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of an open relay is a smtp server that permits anyone that is not physically bound to your network to send mail through it. So anyone on your internal network should be able to send mail through the server to other smtp servers without authentication. However you do not want to extend that ability to the world. Normally all the permit statements are done first and then reject_unauth_destination I have not seen it done the other way around so I am not sure if it works. However you are rejecting the wrong things in your setup. reject_unknown_recipient_domain does not really apply here it is a sender restriction. reject_unauth_destination does nothing here since you are permitting everything with the permit statement. So that is why permits are usually before the reject statements so it knows what to reject. At least that is what makes sense to me.

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination

What this is saying is that it will permit any networks that are defined in mynetworks and permit any users that have properly authenticated with SSL/TLS connection and reject everything else. ie NOT AN OPEN RELAY.

Comment: It's still rejecting NOT the mail based on `reject_unauth_destination` but because of my `check_sender_access`. `Aug 26 18:29:01 <HOSTNAME> postfix/smtpd[20163]: NOQUEUE: discard: RCPT from unknown[10.x.x.x]: <rose661119@yahoo.com.xx>: Recipient address triggers DISCARD action; from=<pbbfbvllnyu@ddd.com> to=<rose661119@yahoo.com.xx> proto=SMTP helo=<PUBLIC-IP>`